# Check access to silent notifications programmatically

Tags: android, android-notifications

In Android, under Settings > (Search for) Device and App Notifications, we can select if we want to enable notification access for an application. Furthermore, it has four checkboxes that we can separately check or uncheck individually.

- Real-time
- Conversations
- Notifications
- Silent

How can an application check if the Silent or Notifications checkboxes or any of the checkboxes are checked or unchecked after access to notifications is granted?

Answer (score 0):

As a normal application you are not allowed to get information form the settings dialog about other applications in case of your own app you can set the `NOTIFICATION_PRIORITY` to make the Notification silent or not. If the user has given you the permission to send notifications with `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>` if not, all notifications are not sent.

Comment: Hi @TIMBLOCKER

I am referring to if an application can check itself if it has been given the permission to access other applications' Silent notifications. The application itself is not sending notifications to the user.

Comment: I know, but as I wrote, you are only able to access your own notifications if the phone is not rooted...